# Laravel how to create fluent Query Builder Join with subquery

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5

I have problems executing:

```
$result = DB::table("SRO_VT_LOG.dbo._LogEventChar AS c with(NOLOCK)")
                ->select('l.CharID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, l.EventTime, GETDATE()) MinutesOnline, l.EventTime OnlineSince, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EventID) AS OnlineCount')
                ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT CharID, MAX(EventTime) EventTime FROM SRO_VT_LOG.dbo._LogEventChar with(NOLOCK) WHERE EventID in (4, 6) GROUP BY CharID) AS l'),
                    function($join)
                    {
                        $join->on('c.EventTime', '=', 'l.EventTime')
                            ->on('c.CharID', '=', 'l.CharID')
                        ;
                    })
            ->get();
```

Error I encountered, i use laravel version 5.5, sql server 2014

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'CharID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, l'. (42S22)
SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'CharID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, l'. (42S22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) you need to specify each field in your `select` separately, whereas yours seems to be in a single string.

An example from the documentation linked above:

`$users = DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email as user_email')->get();`

So I guess you want something like:

```
$result = DB::table("SRO_VT_LOG.dbo._LogEventChar AS c with(NOLOCK)")
                ->select('l.CharID', 'DATEDIFF(MINUTE, l.EventTime, GETDATE()) as MinutesOnline', 'l.EventTime as OnlineSince', 'COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EventID) AS OnlineCount')
                ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT CharID, MAX(EventTime) EventTime FROM SRO_VT_LOG.dbo._LogEventChar with(NOLOCK) WHERE EventID in (4, 6) GROUP BY CharID) AS l'),
                    function($join)
                    {
                        $join->on('c.EventTime', '=', 'l.EventTime')
                            ->on('c.CharID', '=', 'l.CharID')
                        ;
                    })
            ->get();
```

Comment: I've edited, The error is still displayed: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "c.EventTime" could not be bound. (42000)
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "c.EventTime" could not be bound. (42000)

Comment: Ok, that's a different issue, which suggests that the `EventTime` column is not present in table `c`. This is because you've aliased that field to `OnlineSince`, so I suspect you need to use that field name in your join, rather than the underlying true field name?

Comment: What do I need to do next ?, I have checked very carefully and I do not know how to do it properly, I performed in SQL Server Management Studio without error.

Comment: I would guess you want `$join->on('c.OnlineSince', '=', 'l.EventTime')` instead of `$join->on('c.EventTime', '=', 'l.EventTime')` in your join? Probably best to create a new question for this as it's actually a different issue...

Comment: My raw query looks like this: SELECT l.CharID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, l.EventTime, GETDATE()) 'MinutesOnline', l.EventTime 'OnlineSince', COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EventID) 'OnlineCount'
FROM dbo._LogEventChar c with(NOLOCK)
JOIN (SELECT CharID, MAX(EventTime) 'EventTime' FROM dbo._LogEventChar with(NOLOCK) WHERE EventID in (4, 6) GROUP BY CharID) l on c.EventTime = l.EventTime AND c.CharID = l.CharID
WHERE c.EventID = 4
ORDER BY MinutesOnline desc

Comment: Again, probably best to create a new question for this as it's actually a different issue, rather than discussing it in the comments. Then you can give a full description of the issue you're now having.